# Handle redirect function when ASP.NET Core Web MVC error in application startup ( program.cs )

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to handle my net core website able to catch the error and redirect to the error page or other sites if the middleware error or web application build fails at startup.

[image]

Methods I have tried

1.Add custom ErrorHandlerMiddleware and redirect page in trycatch，but redirect cause infinite loop and getting error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
[image]

2.Use "UseExceptionHandler" and errorHandlingPath to Error Controller return and redirect to target page,but getting http error 500

Is it possible to handle redirect to other pages when net core web startup error?

Comment: The statuecode should be 500 if  middleware error or web application build failure

Answer (score 1):

If web application build failed,You may not be able to reach the Error Page

If you want to handle the errors may cause webapplication build failure,you'd better directicty write the response with lambda

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(x => x.Run(async context=> {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("SomeError");
            }));
```